# Complex Least Squares Approximation

Tags: filter-design, least-squares, optimal-filter

In the case of frequency domain FIR filter design, the error function given by :

$$E(\omega)=H(e^{j\omega})-D(e^{j\omega}) \tag{1}$$

is a linear function with respect to the unknown filter coefficients $h[n]$. Hence, the Least Squares frequency domain FIR filter design problem is a linear LS problem which can be solved by computing the solution to a system of linear equations.  (from this: Algorithms for the Constrained Design of Digital Filters with Arbitrary Magnitude and Phase Responses ).

I have a three questions :

- How the error respect the unknown filter coefficient ?
- Does equation (1) is the same : $E(\omega)=D(e^{j\omega})-H(e^{j\omega})~$?
- Does this case is available with negative domain of frequency ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You seem to cite a specific paper. If so please edit your question to include the complete citation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I think there is a lot of valuable general information in [Stanley Pawlukiewicz's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/50875/4298) and in [Royi's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/50856/4298), I think that some specific questions have not been answered, at least as far as I understand the OP's questions.

Let me go through the 3 bullet points in the OP one by one:

1. If you mean how the error function depends on the filter coefficients, then for a length $N$ FIR filter you simply have
   $$H(e^{j\omega})=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}h[n]e^{-jn\omega}=\mathbf{c}^H(\omega)\cdot \mathbf{h}\tag{1}$$

where $\mathbf{h}$ is the vector of filter coefficients, $\mathbf{c}(\omega)$ is given by $\mathbf{c}(\omega)=[1,e^{j\omega},\ldots,e^{j(N-1)\omega}]$, and $^H$ denotes the Hermitian conjugate. Clearly, $(1)$ is a linear function of the filter coefficients, hence the error function $E(\omega)$ is linear in $\mathbf{h}$.

2. The sign of the error function is irrelevant, because you end up minimizing a squared error measure, which depends on $|E(\omega)|^2$, and which is, consequently, independent of the sign of $E(\omega)$.
3. I did my best to understand what is meant by the third question but I failed. Maybe the OP can elaborate in a comment or by editing the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell where to start, so please ignore what is not necessary.

I took an optimization course a number of years ago that was in an EE department using

> Luenberger, David G. Linear and nonlinear programming. Reading, MA:
>   Addison-wesley, 1984.

as one of the texts. I recall asking about Complex Variables and being told that you should just convert your problem to Real Variables.  Given that Luenberger is a Engineer, one feels doubly disappointed.

When one does a least anything (squares included),  you need a relationship $a \le b$  which is obvious for real variables but for Complex number $a < b $ is ambiguous.
In Matlab the test $a < b $ is converted to $|a| < |b| $.  You can have $|a| = |b| $ but that does not mean that $a = b $.  They can differ in phase.

In complex least squares, the objective function is a real function of a complex variable.  In the case $ f(a)= |a| $ or $ g(a)= |a|^2 = a \;\text{conj}(a)$ we can have $g(a)=g(b)$ where $a \ne b$.  In general the Cauchy Reimann condition for a real function of a complex variable is not analytic. $\frac{d}{dx} g(x)$ is flat with respect to phase,

The is fixed by having real function of the form $g( x , \text{conj(x)})$ where $x$ and $\text{conj}(x)$ are considered independent variables. This looks strange but one can  transform $x$ and $\text{conj}(x)$ to $\text{real}(x)$ and $\text{imag}(x)$ and $h( \text{real}(x), \text{imag}(x))$ is perfectly reasonable.

This device is called a Brandwood Derivative.

> Brandwood, D. H. "A complex gradient operator and its application in
>   adaptive array theory." IEE Proceedings H-Microwaves, Optics and
>   Antennas. Vol. 130. No. 1. IET, 1983.

As an example 
$$
\frac{d}{dx^H} x^H R x = Rx $$

There are appendices in

> Van Trees, Harry L. Optimum array processing: Part IV of detection,
>   estimation, and modulation theory. John Wiley & Sons, 2004.

and

> Kailath T, Sayed AH, Hassibi B. Linear estimation. Prentice Hall;
>   2000.

that cover the topic.  Kailath being particularly applicable to least squares.

For more complicated optimizations of real functions of complex variables,

> Sorber, Laurent, Marc Van Barel, and Lieven De Lathauwer.
>   "Unconstrained optimization of real functions in complex variables."
>   SIAM Journal on Optimization 22.3 (2012): 879-898.

This paper is actually worth reading.

Comment: `This paper is actually worth reading.` --- High praise, indeed! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have $ m $ points in the Fourier Domain (Discrete Fourier Domain) for our reference frequency response. We'll designate their values by $ y \in \mathbb{C}^{m} $.

Also we need a filter of $ n $ coefficients to approximate the reference response as good as it can. We'll use $ h $ for that.

We need now the [Fourier Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix), $ F \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n} $ in order to write the following linear complex least squares problem:

$$ \arg \min_{h} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| F h - y \right\|}_{2}^{2} $$

You could easily write this also in a Sum Form.
The nice thing about it is the solution is give by the classic Least Squares solution - $ \hat{h} = {\left( {F}^{H} F \right)}^{-1} {F}^{H} y $.

Of course, in practice, you need many point in frequency domain to add more and more restrictions. You could also write a continuous version of this problem using the DTFT.